# Fast non blocking keyboard IO in C under MinGW

Tags: c, io, mingw

I have written a CPU emulator in C on windows for fun, and I want it to handle its own IO in a non-blocking fashion: if there has been a keypress, return the char value of that keypress, else return 0.

At the moment I am using the following:

```
#include <conio.h>

...

unsigned int input(){
    unsigned int input_data;
    if (_kbhit()){
        input_data = (unsigned int)_getch();
    }
    else{
        input_data = 0;
    }
    return input_data;
}
```

And in terms of function, it is fine. The one problem I have is that it is very detrimental to the speed of the emulator - the emulator can go from 60-100 million instructions per second to the scale of tens or hundreds of thousands, just by running programs with lots of IO instructions. Is there a faster way to do this, whilst still keeping the same functionality?

Comment: Why not just use `_getch()`? [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx): _The `_getch` and `_getwch` functions read a single character from the console without echoing the character._ In other words, once a key press is detected, the function returns. No need for `_kbhit()`. You could also use [`WaitForSingleObjectEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687036(v=vs.85).aspx) to wait on a console input handle, and if the timeout ends before you've received input, then you're not blocking the rest of the program.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I believe I've tried just _getch() before. If I remember correctly (though I could be wrong), it waits for a keypress, whereas I want to return immediately if there is no keypress. I'll try to make that clearer in the question. I will certainly look into WaitForSingleObjectEx(). Thanks.

Comment: Obvious solution: KB reader thread and a volatile char?  You would only need to check the char in your emulator loop:)

Answer (score 1):

Two options comes to my mind:

The first option is the easiest one. Do not check it every time. OS calls are expensive, and if your emulator calls this very often, it will slow everything down.

```
#include <conio.h>
...
unsigned int input(){
    static int cheat = 0;
    cheat = (cheat + 1) % 128;
    if (cheat){
        return 0;
    }
    unsigned int input_data;
    if (_kbhit()){
        input_data = (unsigned int)_getch();
    }
    else{
        input_data = 0;
    }
    return input_data;
}
```

Second option is to receive the actual keyboard input async and store the input data into a buffer. And your input() function checks this buffer. This removes the call to the OS all together in the tight loop.